# Prometheus count request per day to a specific Spring controller endpoint

Tags: java, spring-boot, controller, prometheus

How do I view the number of hits a specific controller endpoint received in a day or x period.

I have quite a basic demo app.  My controller looks like this.

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/person")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PersonController {

  private final PersonService personService;

  @GetMapping(path = "all")
  public List<Person> getAllPerson() {
    return personService.getAllPersons();
  }

  // etc
```

I have configured prometheus and have it running.

[image]

As you can see I have a graph showing for total logback events.

What would the query look like if wanted to show number of times the GET `http://localhost:8080/person/all` as hit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`http_server_requests_seconds_count` or `http_server_requests_seconds_sum` metrics will have the details needed.

For example,

```
http_server_requests_seconds_count{application="xyz",exception="None",method="GET",status="200",uri="/admin/info",} 94078.0
http_server_requests_seconds_sum{application="xyz",exception="None",method="GET",status="200",uri="/admin/info",} 96.108260294
```

Tip: If the prometheus management endpoint is enabled, the prometheus metrics can be viewed in `http://example.com/{actuator|admin}/prometheus`

Comment: whats the difference between sum and count?  is the sum more suitable for graphs?